# Pointer and String Outputs in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, output

I am trying to understand why the following piece of code produces the output of **BCD123 123**.

```
void f(char *p)
{
    *p += 1;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    char a[] = "ABC" "123";
    char *p = a;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        f(p++);

    printf("%s ", a);

    printf("%s ", p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you replaced the whole loop with `p += 3;`, then would you understand why it prints **ABC123 123**?

Comment: `"ABC" "123"` is exactly the same as `"ABC123"`.

Comment: Which bit don't you understand? What were you expecting?

Comment: Well, the output changes to BCD and then why is there only 123 at the end and not another BCD123?

Comment: Do you understand that the 'ASCII' code for `B` is one larger than the ASCII code for `A`?  What do you think `f()` is doing?  What does `*p += 1;` mean?

Comment: Yeah I got that part, but what about at the end when it prints p, there is only 123?

Comment: where did this code come from , was it meant as a test for SO contributors? Did you write it?

Comment: @Promisek3u Because `p` points to the 1 at that point.

Comment: @pm100 Oh it's just from my practice final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void f(char *p)
{
    *p += 1;
}
```

adds 1 to the character passed in. 'A' + 1 = 'B' etc. Look in an ascii table http://www.asciitable.com/

part 2

```
   char a[] = "ABC" "123";
// is the same as 
   char a[] = "ABC123";
      for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            f(p++); <<<<===== moves p along the string 3 places (once for each loop)

        printf("%s ", a);

        printf("%s ", p);  <<< p now points at 4th char
```

Comment: Okay I get it now that since p points to the 4th char it points to 1, then the string prints out the 123. Thank you.